Which method can be used to properly fill a via-in-pad by hand?
Assume that you have a via hole inside a pad. Which method can be used to properly fill a via-in-pad by hand so it will be equal or similar as the protection of vias according to IPC 4761?
Which options can I use, besides filling the via with solder? Can I use copper paste? If yes, which one?

If you hand solder it then you can add more solder to compensate for what the via will absorb so your component will have a good solder joint so... what is the point?

On a board with three or more layers?

@bobflux But what if you have a BGA on that pad?

@DrMoishePippik Yes. 1 or more layers. Main focus is BGA.

@euraad jlcpcb will fill your vias in pads and cover them with a solderable surface for $16.50
